# Error while calling java from PL/SQL

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-ebs

When I call a JAVA class from PL/SQL I get the below error

```
ORA-29532 Java call terminated by uncaught java exception
```

I already referred a metalink note -Doc : 1420943.1

this asks to check the value (`show parameters shared_servers`) and set to Zero if its not zero.
  but the value is already 0.

pls help me to identify ,what is causing the issue.

-----------------------More Information -----------------------------------

We use `loadjava -user apps/password - force -verbose -resolve java.class` to load the java class into the Oracle DB.

Database version 12c.

PL/SQL:

```
l_retCode := initialize(para_1 => l_para1,
                        Para_2 => l_para2,
                        para_3 => l_para3);
```

The initialize function is defined as below

```
function initialize(para_1 VARCHAR2, para_2 VARCHAR2, para_3 VARCHAR2)
return NUMBER as LANGUAGE JAVA NAME
'com.snlp.XXWClass.initialize(java.lang.string,java.lang.string,java.lang.string) return int'
```

Java code:

```
public static int initialize(s String, s1 String , s2 String){
  // logic goes here
}
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] including the java and PL/SQL code you are using; the method you are using to load the java into the database; and an example of how you are calling the procedure/function which generates the error.

Comment: If you execute the java function (outside of Oracle) with the same input parameters does it throw an exception?

Comment: actually this Package + Java code is called from different oracle Forms page. From another page , when we call , its working.. but  I need to call this with this particular parameters, which is throwing this error. Will check this and let you know

Comment: It seems like the new combination of parameter causes your Java method to hurl. So you need to debug the Java code.

Comment: If it helps, use `ods.setURL("jdbc:default:connection");` for creating connection object , instead of driverclass name approach. The above line uses default connection environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the FIX from

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/calling-shell-commands-from-plsql-1-1-129519.pdf

We need to give GRANTS like after logging as APPS(Pls see the link for more clear information- could not copy paste those commands so , i typed - there can be some typos in the below commands) the below commands fixed many issues in our JAVA call from Oracle

```js
dbms_java.grant_permission( '<user_name>', 'SYS:java.util.PropertyPermission', '<property_name>', 'write' );

dbms_java.grant_permission( '<user_name>', 'SYS:java.util.RuntimePermission', 'writeFileDescriptor', '' );

dbms_java.grant_permission( '<user_name>', 'SYS:java.util.RuntimePermission', 'readFileDescriptor', '' );

exec DBMS_JAVA.Grant_Permission( '<user_name>', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission','<<ALL FILES>>','read,write,execute,delete');
```

Answer (score 0):

1) In DB `set serveroutput on` and `exec dbms_java.set_output(10000000);`It allows to see java stack trace in db.

2) Publishing  java class in wrong. Character size is significant. Change java.lang.string.  to java.lang.String.