# Execute a unix command in java through concurrent program

Tags: oracle-ebs

unix commands which are inside java code are not getting executed ,when we try to execute through oracle ebs concurrent program, but when we call from a PL/SQL anonymous block , it works fine.

can some one tell me what is the root cause of this issue

Comment: Grant was the issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134160/error-while-calling-java-from-pl-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to mark this as answered.. so pasting again the solution in the Answer

the issue was , I was not aware of that we need to give grants for executing Java in Oracle. Answer is in the below another SO question

[Error while calling java from PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134160/error-while-calling-java-from-pl-sql)